# onEdit function code not changing when I redeploy my addon

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-addon, triggers

I am writing a Google Sheets Addon, and when I try make changes to my onEdit(e) function, they simply do not reflect. I can make changes to other parts of my addon and it all seems to go through, but right now my onEdit(e) function turns the edited cells red, and nothing - not even deleting the onEdit(e) function - will change that behavior.

I have tried the following:

- Changing the code in my script to change the cell to be yellow instead. Then I Test my script as an addon, choose a brand new sheet that I've just created - and yet the onEdit(e) acts as before.
- I've tried checking my current project's triggers, but the list is blank, as well as all my simple triggers in general.
- I've tried deleting the onEdit(e) method entirely from my project, and deploying that, but it's still there, working on edits.

Not that I think the actual code matters, but my onEdit looks like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  range.setBackground('#ffe599');
}
```

Nothing I seem to try will change or remove that behavior from my addon now :/

Please note I am refreshing the page, and even creating entirely new sheets to install the addon from scratch for each attempt to change this thing.

Any help would be awesome as I'm losing my mind a bit! Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Are you redeploying your addon after each change?

Comment: Aside from re-deploying, have you tried using [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) instead?

Comment: I've tried redeploying, refreshing, and even using a different browser. Will give install-able triggers a go! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote it this way:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName()=='Sheet1') {
    e.range.setBackground('#ffe599');
  }
}
```

And it works for me.  It changes the background when the range is edited by a user.

When I delete the function the background doesn't change on edits any longer.

If I rename the function to something other than onEdit is stops working as well.

I made a little change:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName()=='Sheet1') {
    e.range.setBackground('#ffe599');
    e.range.offset(0,1).setBackground('#ffff00');
  }
}
```

And the changes the background of the cell edited and the one next to it to the right.

Comment: Yeah this is expected behavior! I'm really confused as to why I'm not seeing this